# Apologetics vs. Evangelism?

Tags: apologetics, evangelism, non-christians, proselytizing

When engaging with non-believers, including atheists, agnostics, apatheists, pagans, and others, two distinct approaches come to light:

The first is the **Apologetics** approach, involving the presentation of a rational case for the truth of Christianity via intellectual arguments and evidence. Noteworthy examples include:

- [*Five Proofs of the Existence of God*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1621641333), by Edward Feser
- [*Return of the God Hypothesis: Three Scientific Discoveries That Reveal the Mind Behind the Universe*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0062071505), by Stephen C. Meyer
- [*A Mousetrap for Darwin: Michael J. Behe Answers His Critics*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1936599910), by Michael J. Behe
- [*I Don't Have Enough Faith to Be an Atheist*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1581345615), by Norman L. Geisler and Frank Turek
- [*Answering Atheism: How to Make the Case for God with Logic and Charity*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1938983432), by Trent Horn
- [*Mere Christianity*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0060652926), by C. S. Lewis
- [*Warranted Christian Belief*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0195131932), by Alvin Plantinga
- [*The Case for the Resurrection of Jesus*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B001QOGJY0), by Gary R. Habermas and Michael R. Licona
- [*Miracles: The Credibility of the New Testament Accounts*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0801039525), by Craig S. Keener

The second approach is **Evangelism**, with Spirit and power. The Apostle Paul advocates for this approach in 1 Corinthians 2:1-5:

> <sup>**1**</sup> And I, brethren, when I came to you, did not come with excellence of speech or of wisdom declaring to you the testimony of God. <sup>**2**</sup> For I determined not to know anything among you except Jesus Christ and Him crucified. <sup>**3**</sup> I was with you in weakness, in fear, and in much trembling. <sup>**4**</sup> **And my speech and my preaching were not with persuasive words of human wisdom, but in demonstration of the Spirit and of power**, <sup>**5**</sup> **that your faith should not be in the wisdom of men but in the power of God**.

Considering these two approaches to proselytizing, my question is as follows:

Are there established and widely recognized principles in Christianity that guide the decision of when to prioritize the approach of evangelism over apologetics, or vice versa? More specifically, is the preaching of the gospel with Spirit and power in evangelism always the preferred method, relegating the use of sophisticated philosophical arguments often associated with apologetics to a secondary and complementary role?

Comment: Aren't apologetics usually used with people who are already Christians, but are having doubts? And while they might be written as if non-believers are the intended audience, I feel like I don't hear many stories of people who were logic-ed in to Christianity.

Comment: There are differing thoughts on what good apologetics is.  I hold to the view that has been popularized by teachers like Cornelius Van Til, K. Scott Oliphint, John Frame, and others.  When you view apologetics that way, it's often hard to distinguish evangelism and apologetics.  Or perhaps apologetics is just the beginning stages of evangelism.  I'd recommend looking at what Oliphint has taught on Covenantal Apologetics.

Comment: If you look at apologetics in the early church it's evident that they were aimed at refuting attacks on the faith and thus reassuring Christians than on winning people to Christ, though they were often posed as trying to persuade.  But apologetics rarely wins anyone over; the best that can be done, as C. S. Lewis once noted, is to show that the Christian faith is not unreasonable.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

For Gospel-minded Christians, sharing the Gospel must be the priority. So yes, evangelism is typically the driving approach. Apologetics is then *a tool* that can be utilised in evangelism when specific stumbling blocks are encountered. As everyone has different things they find easy to accept about the Gospel and others they find hard, there's no single way to effectively use apologetics, it needs to be tailored to the individual's concerns.

But apologetics is not only about convincing unbelievers that Christianity is rational. It's arguably even more important for people who are already Christian, to give them an intellectual foundation that will hold up to the pressure of competing belief systems, and to strengthen them when they go through times of doubt.

Comment: +1 i like the idea of apologetics as evangelical tool. In that sense,  apologetics is an avenue or tool to reach those of an intellectual orientation. A camp meeting is an evangelical tool for those who can be moved by powerful preaching amidst a "cloud of witnesses." A direct testimony from an close friend can also be a powerful form of evangelism. Paul  and others were moved by a personal revelation, not preaching or testimony.  Others are born into a faith and inherit it from their families, then come to "own" their faith either gradually or after dramatic test.. One size does not fit all.

Comment: Good answer.  An example of the crossover is Acts 17.  First Paul was disputing (apologetics) then he got invited to speak in the Areopagus (evangelism).  He was also asked to speak again on the matter and, if he did, it would likely have been more apologetic, I think. +1

Answer (score 3):

#### Expanding the horizon of "evangelism"

First, a note about how you frame evangelism.  Evangelism is broader than "preaching of the gospel with Spirit and power" which smacks of the now prevalent charismatic approach of

- wanting to see evidence of "Holy Spirit" working in *sudden conviction* of the heart in the hearers, or
- wanting to see evidence of "power" in seemingly *supernatural phenomena* such as miraculous healing, prophetic "word of knowledge" that is personally tailored to a specific person in the audience, etc.

That's too narrow.  The verse you quoted (from Paul's letter to the Corinthian church) was tailored to the Corinthian's church's need; **it is insufficient as a definition** although Charismatics love to emphasize Paul's coverage of spiritual gifts (given by the Holy Spirit) and the manifestations of power in the absence of "human wisdom".  Paul's specific rebuke (the context of the verse) doesn't mean he rules out the role of "human wisdom" when talking to other people.

In the New Testament time (1st century AD), the main sense for "evangelist" is the 'angel' (messenger) of 'good news' (see [etymology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evangelism#Etymology)), so the root meaning of "evangelism" is naturally the act of proclamation.  But in Christianity, **Jesus himself *IS* the good news and its proclaimer**, thus 1) the gospel, 2) the messenger, and  3) the proclamation are rolled into one person, sent into the world by God himself as his self revelation (special revelation).  So we shouldn't reduce evangelism to mere communication of propositions to be believed, but the evangelist should ALSO embody the proclamation like Jesus. Yes, there ***IS*** a place for spiritual gifts and miracles in evangelism, but they should serve as *sign*, not essence, let alone the criteria of success as Charismatics would have it.

Secondly, **evangelism's goal is *lasting conversion***, whether it is sudden or years-long.  Evangelists do not control the Holy Spirit, they are merely *partners* while the Holy Spirit simultaneously and independently (with His own timeline) works on the heart of each would-be-believer to personally prepare the heart of the person using the person's circumstances and God's life plan for that person.  The Holy Spirit is the better agent for this task because God knows each heart intimately, more than the person knows himself/herself, not to mention the evangelist.

Thus, a **wise evangelist** would be sensitive to select the appropriate approach to use for a particular person, which makes getting to know the person *FIRST* very critical so that as a partner of the Holy Spirit he/she can be His vehicle to speak the right words into the particular circumstance of the person.  [This article is a good example](https://adosc.org/what-style-of-evangelism-best-fits-you/) to widen the horizon of evangelism beyond the typical **direct approach** of proclaiming of the gospel and the **invitational approach** which usually follows preaching:

- **intellectual approach**: strategically destroy false reasons for rejecting the gospel
- **testimonial approach**: people love personal stories, in this case how you yourself came to Jesus and your faith journey with Jesus
- **relational approach**: starts with friendship showing how Jesus befriends everyone even today
- **service approach**: soften the heart through loving service that Jesus himself did

And we shouldn't forget **lifestyle evangelism** by simply BEING a Christian in the world through imaging Jesus in our interaction with others especially at workplaces, schools, and activities (restaurants, sports, music events, clubs, etc).

#### Expanding the horizon of "apologetics"

The [etymology of "apologetics"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apologia#Etymology) is *apologia*, which means "a speech in defense".  Although you are right that the contemporary usual meaning of "apologetics" is "presentation of a rational case for the truth of Christianity via intellectual arguments and evidence", I think we can make the case that the meaning in Christian practice is also too narrow.  *apologia* as a speech is *more general* than the "rational case".

But Christians can take one step further: *apologia* does NOT necessarily have to take the form of a rational argument or a speech.  Should we say that select martyrs and Jesus himself were *NOT* apologists simply because they didn't explicitly present a rational case for Christianity and didn't have an eloquent speech?  I'll argue that in Christianity ***apologia* can ALSO be embodied**, following the pattern of Jesus who provides the defense **in his own person** (nail holes on his hands and feet), St. Paul who carry marks of his being whipped and beaten in his body, and others who are persecuted because of the gospel.

Non-persecution-related suffering can also count as *apologia*, especially effective if the person we are evangelizing to has *also* experienced tremendous suffering (loss of child, cancer, etc).
Consider C.S. Lewis's own suffering of the loss of his wife Joy to cancer (yes, he is one of the greatest 20th century intellectual apologists, but now that we have more of his letters and biographies, his own LIFE provides another dimension of Christian apology).  Or consider [the testimony of Carol Cross](https://vimeo.com/179507680) who suffered the loss of one child and is co-suffering with another child with life-long disease.  In both cases, narrowing evangelism to charismatic style "Spirit and power" proclamation will be **counterproductive** because Jesus didn't plan to heal Joy or Carol's two kids.  Everyone will eventually die, but a suffering Christian who dies in faith and with praise on his/her lips is an *apologia* in person.

Thus, a **wise apologist** would know the limit of rational presentation, especially when the audience doesn't care much for reason, but need answers in the form of *meaning of life* that Christianity boldly claims to possess, especially in this time of nihilism.  This is despite Christianity's rationally insufficient theodicies, to which we need not apologize since Jesus himself is the ultimate sufferer *beyond* His physical suffering on the cross.  Catholic philosopher Eleonore Stump argues that on the cross Jesus read the mind of every single one of the BILLIONS of people past, present, and future (including their suffering) as an act of divine compassion, possible because in his divine nature Jesus is omniscient.  Thus it's not a surprise that on the cross Jesus seemed to lose sight of God, crying 'Eloi, Eloi, lama sabachthani', the cry of many intense sufferers.

#### Conclusion

Yes, "evangelism" and "apologetics" have distinct meanings and distinct approaches; the former's root idea is "proclamation" while the latter's is "explanation".  But in Christianity "proclamation" and "explanation" can go **beyond** propositions and rational argument, since the *gospel we are proclaiming* and the ultimate *explanation of the gospel* are both the **ONE person Jesus Christ**, and Christians are His ambassadors who act as both evangelist and apologist.

You asked:

> Are there established and widely recognized principles in Christianity that guide the decision of when to prioritize the approach of evangelism over apologetics, or vice versa?

I can identify two such principles:

1. FIRST is **the principle of embodying Jesus IN our lives as ambassadors through compassion, words and deeds by knowing and loving each person we are proselytizing.** The New Testament and the 2,000 year of Christian history provides us with countless examples, which includes the lives of the saints.  **Serving others in this context means listening to their specific challenges in raising the horizon of their lives to the eternal horizon.**  After we know the challenge they are facing in comprehending and accepting the gospel, we provide the missing piece or refer them to someone who can.

   - For some, the challenge can be addressed by apologetics (traditionally more narrowly defined).
   - For others, they need to hear the gospel proclaimed through the lens of our personal life history.
   - For all, seeing our lives as good ambassadors of Christ can oil the way.

   Finally, we should take care *not* to sully the reputation of Jesus by acting contrary to what Jesus would have done.
2. SECOND is **the principle of how human psyche works, in which DESIRE, WILL and INTELLECT are tightly interconnected** even in little kids who have *desires* to reach for more cookies than what's good for them necessitating their responsible parents to speak *reason* to that act hoping the kids would listen for their own good and modify their *will*.  More formally, see [a diagram of Thomistic 12 stage analysis of the human act](https://storage.homework-api-v2.zookal.com/uploads/store/576519883/b7d48cc3-1de5-463b-aa52-12a62ea01a96.jpg) showing the interconnectedness of the INTELLECT (more general than how moderns define REASON) and WILL in which DESIRE is satisfied in various ways.  Applying to evangelism and apologetics:

   - evangelism as *gospel proclamation* (the "do this" part) is an appeal to the WILL side
   - apologetics as *gospel explanation* (the "why" part) is an appeal to the INTELLECT side

   Every person has different disposition; in some their INTELLECT needs correction or satisfaction.  In others their WILL need some prodding and steering in the eternal direction.  A wise evangelist and apologist (in a loving, compassionate, serving manner) would identify the missing element and aim to supply it to the hearer.  Evangelists who don't nurture the INTELLECT side (when needed) or Apologists who don't nurture the WILL side (when needed) will not have sufficient power to present human DESIRE with the ultimate and eternal satisfaction that in Christianity terminates in fellowship with God through Jesus Christ.

Comment: @Mark If you read my answer before the final version 14 hours later.  I think I'm done now.

Comment: Good answer. Question: what exegesis of 1 Corinthians 2:1-5 are you using? Here are parallel commentaries: https://biblehub.com/commentaries/1_corinthians/2-5.htm. None of the commentaries mentions miracles or the charismata. It's certainly possible, but, as far as I understand the commentaries, it's not logically entailed by the passage.

Comment: Sorry, in  the parallel commentaries of 1 Corinthians 2:4 there are mentions of miracles: https://biblehub.com/commentaries/1_corinthians/2-4.htm. However, many acknowledge room for nuance. For instance: *"But in demonstration of the Spirit; by which Grotius and some others understand miracles, by which the doctrine of the gospel was at first confirmed; but Vorstius and many others better understand by it the Holy Ghost’s powerful and inward persuasion of men’s minds, of the truth of what was preached by Paul"*.

Comment: Evangelism must always be accompanied by the influencing activity of the Holy Spirit in order to provoke genuine conversions (with or without miracles involved), would you agree?

Comment: @Mark  Of course.  The main point of my email is the *mode* of how humans participate in conjunction of the work of the Holy Spirit (which has unknowable and knowable aspects as well as empirical and non-empirical effects).  I also argue that the mode is more full orbed than propositions and arguments (i.e. personal embodiment, compassionate and serving rather than presenting cold facts and explanation).  In my other answer, I tried to conceptualize one of the effects of the Holy Spirit in terms of providing "light of faith" manifested (in the observable interior of the soul as the "aha").

Comment: @Mark the paradigmatic example of a true evangelist and a true apologist should be Jesus himself, while not exhausting what humans can potentially do.  Aquinas does more in being apologist than Jesus.  My point is that 1) message content, 2) messenger, and 3) the proclamation should ideally be fused into the being and the living of evangelist/apologist, following Jesus where the fusion is perfect, though not exhaustive, giving room for C.S. Lewis, Eleonore Stump, and others to expand.

Comment: @Mark I used to be confused how a person can be Truth and Way, but this way of defining evangelism through the fusion helped me understand the meaning of [The 7 'I AM' statements of Jesus in the Gospel of John](https://www.crosswalk.com/faith/bible-study/what-is-the-significance-of-the-7-i-am-statements-in-john.html#google_vignette).  The Thomistic Institute lecture on Truth also helped me, by seeing Jesus as Truth-maker to whom our own truths (embodied in our lives) are to be measured.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151716/discussion-between-gratefuldisciple-and-mark).

Answer (score 2):

**Fallacy of Logic** There is a fallacy of logic called the Either/Or Fallacy.
Understanding of this reveals the fact that quite often there are more answer to a dilemma than "two" that were presented. We must be careful not to commit this fallacy here.

**No Gap** There really is no gap (like the Grand Canyon) between Evangelism (personal or public) and Apologetics (logical or miraculous). Apologetics without Evangelism--the presentation of THE GOSPEL--is merely philosophical diatribe. And Evangelism without Apologetics--confirmation--is a "form of Christianity without the power!

**Apostolic Customs** Taken and presented together, people are convicted, convinced, and converted. This was the custom of the first century Apostles. Classic example of apologetics presentation (Natural Theology) to introduce the Gospel, is Paul's evangelism on Mars Hill in Athens. Another is the introduction to the book sent to the Romans (Chapters 1-2). Many other times, Acts recorded the effectiveness of Believers in converting villages with a combination of proclaiming the Gospel **and** confirming the message with miracles.

> With great power the Apostles gave witness of the Resurrection of the Lord Jesus(apologetic confirmation of the Gospel).(Acts 4:33)

> And the people with one accord gave heed to those things which Philip spoke, hearing and seeing the miracles which he did. (Acts 8:6)

> Then Paul stood in the midst of Mars Hill, and said...And when they heard of the resurrection...others said, "we will hear thee again of this matter...certain men clung to him and believed... (Acts 17:16-34)

The tool kit of the Evangelist has many instruments which are used at various events to various degrees. It even contains a hoe because **Apologetics is pulling weeds so that Gospel seeds can be planted**. And on the other hand, Apologetics works with Evangelism as a herbicide to prevent seeds of doubt from sprouting and choking out the Gospel news in new believers.

**Versus?** It is inappropriate to mention *versus* in conjunction with E and A. No more than it would be customary to say "Peanut butter OR jelly," "Jack OR Jill," "Faith OR hope OR love".  Both / And are words that best represent the awesome ministry of presenting the Gospel to a dying world. Peace.

> And Jesus said unto the disciples, "Go ye into all the world, and preach the Gospel to every creature...**and** these signs shall follow them... (Mark 16:15-17)

> Ye shall receive power after the Holy Spirit is come upon you, **and** ye shall be witnesses for Me...unto the uttermost part of the Earth. (Acts 1:8)

{P.S. The poster of this Answer has taught Apologetics in schools for 25 years; and has written textbooks on Apologetics and on Evangelism. He advocates all varieties of Apologetics and all types of Evangelism, knowing that it all depends on the accepted Epistemology of the hearers.}